# In how many distinguishable ways can ten nickels, two dimes, and two pennies be arranged in a row?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

In how many distinguishable ways can ten nickels, two dimes, and two pennies be arranged in a row?, assuming that the coins all have different dates and so are distinguishable from each other, and the two dimes cannot be adjacent to each other, and the two pennies cannot be adjacent to each other.

I know that that there are 14 factorial arrangements without the adjacent condition, but am not sure how to do the adjacent part

Comment: Choose ten places out of the fourteen to place the nickels, then choose two out of the remaining four to place the dimes.

Comment: so the answer would be 14!-(10 choose 14 x 4 choose 2)?

Comment: i mean 14 choose 10

Comment: if 'all coins...have...dates', it means all coins are distinguishable

Comment: Yea so i dont think that's right

Comment: The question in the body seems to be completely different from the one in the title.

Comment: I'm sorry i did not think I could fit the entire question in the title.

Comment: Sorry, I just looked at the title question and assumed that coins of the same denomination were indistinguishable (and didn't see the adjacency requirement).

Comment: Also, I would like to pose a sub question, if "all coins have different dates and are distinguishable from each other" was taken out, then there would be 14 choose 10 ways times 4 choose 2 ways, but then what would be the exclusion part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use inclusion/exclusion principle:

- Include the number of arrangements: $(10+2+2)!$
- Exclude the number of arrangements with the dimes adjacent: $(10+1+2)!2!$
- Exclude the number of arrangements with the pennies adjacent: $(10+2+1)!2!$
- Include the number of arrangements with both types adjacent: $(10+1+1)!2!2!$

The total number of arrangements is therefore:

$$(10+2+2)!-(10+1+2)!2!-(10+2+1)!2!+(10+1+1)!2!2!=64186214400$$

Comment: can you also answer my subquestion in the comments above please, thanks!

Comment: @Cantwait428: $\frac{14!}{10!2!2!}-\frac{13!}{10!1!2!}-\frac{13!}{10!2!1!}+\frac{12!}{10!1!1!}$.

Comment: @Cantwait428: You're welcome :)

Comment: to clarify, is that (14 choose 10)-(13 choose 10)-(13 choose 10)+(12 choose 10)?

Comment: Looking at it again i guess it's not exactly that

Answer (score 1):

1) We can arrange the nickels in a row in $10!$ ways, creating 11 gaps.

2) a) If the dimes are in different gaps, there are $11\cdot10$ ways to place the dimes in their gaps.

$\hspace{.29 in}$There are now 13 gaps, so there are
$13\cdot 12$ ways to place the pennies in distinct gaps.

$\hspace{.12 in}$b) If the dimes are in the same gap, there are 11 ways to choose the gap and 2 ways to order the dimes in

$\hspace{.29 in}$the gap.  Then there are 2 choices of the penny to go between the dimes, and then 12 gaps in which to

$\hspace{.29 in}$place the other penny.

This gives a total of $10![11\cdot10\cdot13\cdot12+22\cdot24]=\color{red}{64,186,214,400}$ possibilities.